# Where is SG_IO sense data stored?

Tags: hdparm

I'm getting the following error message when running `hdparm -S` on my external USB hard drive:

```
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data
```

Where is this sense data stored on the hard drive? I never encountered this error before, so I'm assuming something on the drive went corrupt.

Comment: Here is a good explanation of the issue you're having:[Hard Drive error: bad/missing sense data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768373/hard-drive-error-bad-missing-sense-data)

Comment: @galoget That answer makes it seem it's a hardware issue ("drive controller doesn't support that method of enquiry, not all usb sata chipsets are created equal"). As I said in my question, `hdparm -S` worked before with the hard drive, but only now does it return the "SG_IO: bad/missing sense data". Did my hardware go bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to use:

```
sdparm -rs SCT=600 /dev/my_disk
sdparm -rC stop /dev/my_disk
```

instead of

```
hdparm -S 12 /dev/my_disk
hdparm -y /dev/my_disk
```

respectively.

(courtesy [this table of `sdparm`'s equivalents of `hdparm` commands](http://sg.danny.cz/sg/sdparm.html#mozTocId262297))

Answer (score 2):

`hdparm` is communicating with the driver controller firmware. It is requesting the sensor data from there. Here it might be that the controller/firmware does not support this command/operation or the tool is not the right for your controller/firmware.

If interested in more background information and details you may follow up at  [Linux SCSI Generic (sg) Driver](http://sg.danny.cz/sg/), [Python-SCSI](https://github.com/rosjat/python-scsi) or [t10.org](http://www.t10.org/).

Comment: I did encounter the issue after upgrading my Linux kernel (I think to 4.14.14 or 4.14.15), so maybe it is the sg driver that changed.